# GraphAPI com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm using microsoft graph api version 2.3.2 to upload/download the document with sharepoint.

My uploading functionality is working fine. But to download the document randomly sometime facing `com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request` issue `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: null`

I'm using following code to download the document from sharepoint.

```
IDriveItemRequest iDriveItemRequest = microsoftGraphClient.drives(driveId).root().itemWithPath("folder1/folder2/folder3/temp.docx").buildRequest();
DriveItem driveItem = iDriveItemRequest.get();
InputStream inputStream = microsoftGraphClient.drives(driveId).items(driveItem.id).content().buildRequest().get();
```

Please let me know what could be the solution. I've tried to upgrade Graph API version with 2.6.0 but face the same issue.

Log stack-trace:

```
com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:471) ~[microsoft-graph-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:220) ~[microsoft-graph-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.send(CoreHttpProvider.java:200) ~[microsoft-graph-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.BaseStreamRequest.send(BaseStreamRequest.java:88) ~[microsoft-graph-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.DriveItemContentStreamRequest.get(DriveItemContentStreamRequest.java:52) ~[microsoft-graph-2.3.2.jar:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.repository.sharepoint.SharePointDocumentRepository$findDocument$contentToStream$1$1.invoke(SharePointDocumentRepository.kt:66) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.repository.sharepoint.SharePointDocumentRepository$findDocument$contentToStream$1$1.invoke(SharePointDocumentRepository.kt:43) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.repository.sharepoint.SharePointUtilKt.retry(SharePointUtil.kt:17) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.repository.sharepoint.SharePointUtilKt.retry$default(SharePointUtil.kt:12) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.repository.sharepoint.SharePointDocumentRepository$findDocument$contentToStream$1.invoke(SharePointDocumentRepository.kt:66) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.repository.sharepoint.SharePointDocumentRepository$findDocument$contentToStream$1.invoke(SharePointDocumentRepository.kt:43) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.common.model.documenten.DocumentStream.writeContent(Document.kt:70) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.rest.resources.DocumentDownloadResource.sendDocument(DocumentDownloadResource.kt:37) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.rest.resources.DocumentDownloadResource.download(DocumentDownloadResource.kt:28) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.rest.resources.DownloadResource.download(DownloadResource.kt:22) ~[main/:na]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.rest.resources.DownloadResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d57e6616.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at nl.dexter.documenten.rest.resources.DownloadResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5426d937.download(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor256.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:755) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1617) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:226) ~[websocket-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:65) ~[brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:57) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:61) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:86) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:214) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at nl.dexter.common.authentication.MDCFilter.doFilterInternal(MDCFilter.kt:25) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at nl.dexter.common.CustomerPortalFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomerPortalFilter.kt:44) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at nl.dexter.common.context.RequestMetadataFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestMetadataFilter.kt:27) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at nl.dexter.common.CorrelationIdFilter.doFilterInternal(CorrelationIdFilter.kt:30) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter.java:74) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter.java:92) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:214) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:86) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-8.0.2.jar:8.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:82) ~[brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:138) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566) ~[jetty-security-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1607) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1297) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:485) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1577) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1212) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:270) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-io-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[jetty-io-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) ~[jetty-io-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:388) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: null
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.prepareToConnect(Transmitter.java:129) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:79) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RedirectHandler.intercept(RedirectHandler.java:123) ~[microsoft-graph-core-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.RetryHandler.intercept(RetryHandler.java:140) ~[microsoft-graph-core-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.AuthenticationHandler.intercept(AuthenticationHandler.java:31) ~[microsoft-graph-core-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.httpcore.TelemetryHandler.intercept(TelemetryHandler.java:37) ~[microsoft-graph-core-1.0.5.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81) ~[okhttp-3.14.6.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.graph.http.CoreHttpProvider.sendRequestInternal(CoreHttpProvider.java:398) ~[microsoft-graph-2.3.2.jar:na]
    ... 163 common frames omitte
```

Comment: I havent tried with the Graph SDK latest one, but with Graph API - it works for me. Just to isolate the issue, you can try the above call in graph explorer and see still you can repro the issue or not. This will help us to isolate the issue with the SDK or with API call or with tenant itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in the SDK triggered by a change in the service behavior. (transfer encoding chunked)

The bug has been fixed and is available in release [1.0.8 of of the core library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-core/milestone/10?closed=1)

Comment: Thanks @baywet, 
So it is resolved in 2.7.1. right?

Comment: The version of the microsoft-graph asset doesn't matter, it's core you have to make sure it's 1.0.8 and above. However with 2.7.0  we bumped the reference to core. So if you don't have another reference in your project to core with a different version, upgrading the main library will upgrade core as well.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @baywet I have few queries regarding this change
1. When this change got rolled out? And is there any documentation for the same? Is this a phase rollout?
2. What is the purpose regarding this change?
3. Is there any behaviour change in the MS-Java sdk or testing impact that we should be aware of?
4. Can we disable this change from azure console?

Comment: 4. you don't have control over this service change. 3. the impacted behavior from that service change has been fixed in the SDK, the only thing that's required is for you to upgrade your application. 2. the service change was to improve latency for customers. 1. The behavior has always been there on the service, but only on a very small percentage of endpoints. Since late January it's being rolled out to more and more endpoints, hence why customers started noticing the issue.